# input type date only for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datepicker

I am trying to make time and date picker for my project. I want to time and date picker I will use one plugins, but that's only for desktop browsers and when it will browse on mobile it will trigger mobile native time/date picker. I was looking that type plugins, but I don't get it yet. If you guys know then please let me know. I tried to do something add/remove class Depending on Screen Size. It adds and remove class, but plugins not fired.

bellow is my code

https://codepen.io/pagol/pen/MOzVMP

**html**

```
<div class="datepicker test">
<input type="date" class="change" id="myinput">
</div>
```

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  TinyDatePicker('.test input');

}); 

$(function(){

$(window).bind("resize",function(){
    console.log($(this).width())
    if($(this).width() <500){
    $('.datepicker').removeClass('test').addClass('red')
    }
    else{
    $('div').removeClass('red').addClass('test')
    }
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fire TinyDatePicker (that i do not know about) after adding the class. Here you are just adding classes without attaching TinyDatePicker :

```
var dp = null;
attachDatePicker = function(){
    if(dp === null || typeof dp === 'undefined')
        dp = TinyDatePicker('.test input');
}

$(function(){
    $(window).bind("resize",function(){
        console.log($(this).width())
        if($(this).width() <500){
            $('.datepicker').removeClass('test').addClass('red');
            //you should alsa remove TinyDatePicker here
            if(dp !== null){
                dp.destroy();
                dp = null;
            }
        }
        else{
            $('div').removeClass('red').addClass('test');
            attachDatePicker();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  attachDatePicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks...Cool this is almost work. it not really doesn't meter TinyDatePicker or any other picker. if you want to try for live anywhere you can  use any other picker. i have another idea like for desktop we can change input type date to text and mobile view type to date .. what do you think ?

Comment: Haven't tested but i updated my code (after rapidly reading doc here https://github.com/chrisdavies/tiny-date-picker/blob/master/docs/tiny-date-picker.md ), try something like this.

Comment: cool .. super cool. .. almost work.. one thing not work yet.. which is when it is load in mobile plugins fired still but if screen size that to desktop to mobile size then work fine. i am going to test in real mobile..  i think we need to do something like when load in mobile view it then plugins also not fired. current it is fired by default

Comment: Check if client is a mobile with "if (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined'){ ... }" looks better than size to me.

Comment: thanks i am trying.. manly it first need to fix onload mobile will be plugins not fired and desktop will fired.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom build of [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download/?inputtypes-setclasses):

*(You only need to include the input type fields).*

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    TinyDatePicker('.test input');    
  }); 
}
```

This will check if the browser has native support for input `type="date"`. If not then it will use your custom datepicker.

Comment: thanks.. actually i intentionally want to fired native date and time picker in mobile. because mobile user use to with native time and date picture for selection. so my idea is for mobile user give them facility for native  date/time picker and for desktop/laptop user use any plugins

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

finally i able to fix what i wanted to do. so now if load in mobile it will fired native picker and if browser in desktop/laptop it will fired date picker js.

live code here `codepen.io/pagol/pen/MOzVMP`